# Android: unable to evaluate locals while debugging in eclipse

Tags: android

Ever since updating my android sdk and eclipse plugin, I cannot see the values of local variables while debugging in eclipse.  This worked fine previously.  Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution?

Late edit, but an important note:

This only happens for classes in projects marked as "Is Library".  I have 2 projects, one of which is marked as an android library, the other of which utilizes this library.  When I run an activity from the second project, I can evaluate local variables for its classes but not the library classes.

Comment: Please give exact versions and any errors

Comment: I have tried compiling with sdk 4.0.3 and 2.2.  And running on 2.2, and 3.1 devices. (unlikely that the sdk version number matters).  Could you point me to where I can find the ddms plugin version number?  The error is that when I place a breakpoint in my code, local variables cannot be evaluated.  They show as blank in the "variables" view and "inspecting" them with eclispse gives "x cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: I should clarify that member variables (class level variables) do evaluate.  Its only local variables (method parameters and variables declared within methods) which do not.

Comment: Sounds almost like an optimization setting. This sort of thing happens in C/C++ when debugging heavily optimized code, but I realize this is entirely different. Could this be a difference in JIT-compilers?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I have the problem that I have to reboot Eclipse cause it is not connecting correctly to the emulator(or the device) on debug-mode.  Otherwise, you can also try by going to your

> /android-sdk/platform-tools/

folder and there, run adb.

You can try to reboot the demon and so on by running

> adb kill-server

and after, start it again by:

> adb start-server

Hope it is going to work.....Otherwise the other solution could be to reinstall the Android plugin to see if there was a problem there....

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the two things:

1. Window -> Reset perspective..
2. Just close that "Variable" window and reopen.

Comment: The message "x cannot be resolved to a variable" looks like x is out of scope. Were you able to run _exactly_ the same code before the upgrade?

Comment: yes. I assume the upgrade in some way effected the way the app is packaged when it runs from eclipse, such that everything in the debugger is out of scope.  or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to share the code with us?

[image: Debug perspective]

Comment: it happens for all my code, including super simple test cases I made to confirm the issue. I'm confident it is not related to specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with
Window>Preferences>Java>Compiler>Compliance and Classfiles
check ON "Add variable attributes to generated class files (used by debugger)"